# Why is my ThreadAbortException behaving differently with C# 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-5.0, c#-6.0, threadabortexception

I have an ASP.NET MVC (5.2.3) application that uses Response.Redirect during authorization (I know this is bad, I plan to fix this, but humor my question). As we know this throws a `ThreadAbortException`, but the pipeline catches (and presumably `ResetAbort()`s) this before IIS needs to handle the exception.

After changing my build server to build with the VS2015 version of MSBuild (instead of the 2013 version), these exceptions are no longer handled and my appdomain shuts down after 5 instances of Response.Redirect being called (as per the appdomain settings - 5 unhandled exceptions in 5 minutes == disable the app pool).

I can't figure out why *simply changing the compiler version* changes the behaviour of the runtime such that the ThreadAbortExceptions are no longer handled. I did not change the .net framework version - it remained at 4.5.

I have a number of solutions to try in mind (upgrade framework version, don't call Redirect, etc), but I'm struggling to figure out how this actually happened.

Comment: Are you sure nothing else changed?

Comment: @svick 100% sure nothing but the compiler was changed between builds

Comment: Is `Response.Redirect("/foo", false)` not an option?

Comment: Try inserting a `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()` call somewhere to see if this has the same effect. Also, you probably should disable that ASP.NET setting *always* because it causes downtime until manual intervention and it does nothing good. This setting is the devil. Unfathomable how this can be default enabled.

Comment: @x0n I already know the workarounds, I'm trying to understand the root cause

Comment: You asked me on Twitter to have a look at this question, but I have no idea what's going on here, sorry!